# Add fields to a form with Ajax

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a little problem with my form. I try to create a button that adds dynamically some fields with Ajax.

I created a fieldset in order to group this fields.
But it's seems that the form state that handle the number of items is not kept (nb_package), and it's stuck to 2 when i click on the add button (Ajouter un package).

I tried some example but it didn't work...

```
namespace Drupal\module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ArmateurAddBoat extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'armateur_add_boat';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->generationListes();
    $form_state->disableRedirect();
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/addboat';
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

    $form['packages'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="packages-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $nb_package = $form_state->get('nb_package');
    if (!isset($nb_package)) {
      $nb_package = 1;
      $form_state->set('nb_package', $nb_package);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $nb_package; $i++) {

      $form['packages'][$i]['titre_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#prefix' => '<div class="package-item"><div class="row">',
        '#title' => $this->t('Nom de la période'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['date_debut_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => $this->t('Début de la période'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['date_fin_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => $this->t('Début de la période'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['horaire_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $this->t('Horaire'),
        '#options' => $this->_horaires,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
        '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['cocktail_capacite_max_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Capacité max'),
        '#min' => 0,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['cocktail_capacite_min_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Capacité min'),
        '#min' => 0,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['repas_capacite_max_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Capacité max'),
        '#min' => 0,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
      ];

      $form['packages'][$i]['repas_capacite_min_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'number',
        '#title' => $this->t('Capacité min'),
        '#min' => 0,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#suffix' => '</div></div></div>',
      ];
    }

    $form['ajouter_package'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Ajouter une période'),
      //'#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn btn-primary'], 'id' => 'add-package'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'AddPackageCallback'],
        'wrapper' => 'packages-wrapper',
      ],
      '#submit' => [$this, 'AddPackageSubmited'],
      '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
    ];

    if ($nb_package > 1) {
      $form['retirer_package'] = [
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => $this->t('Retirer une période'),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['btn btn-submit'],
          'event' => 'click',
          'id' => 'remove-package',
        ],
      ];
    }

    $form['ajouter'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Créer le bateau'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public function AddPackageCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $i = $form_state->get('nb_package');
    $i++;
    $form_state->set('nb_package', $i);
    \Drupal::logger('debug')->debug($i);
    return $form['packages'];
  }

  public function AddPackageSubmited(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $nb_package = $form_state->get('nb_package') + 1;
    $form_state->set('nb_package', $nb_package);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }
}
```

Thanks :),

Comment: You can't change $form_state in an ajax callback. Do this in buildForm(). There you can check `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()` for the ajax action if you have more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the callback and the submit method and now it works :) :

```
namespace Drupal\module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ArmateurAddBoat extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'armateur_add_boat';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->generationListes();
    $form_state->disableRedirect();
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'module/addboat';
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
 $form['packages'] = [
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="packages-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $nb_package = $form_state->get('nb_package');

    if (is_null($nb_package)) {
      $nb_package = 1;
      $form_state->set('nb_package', $nb_package);
    }

for ($i = 0; $i < $nb_package; $i++) {

  $form['packages'][$i]['titre_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="package-item"><div class="row">',
    '#title' => $this->t('Nom de la période'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['date_debut_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => $this->t('Début de la période'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['date_fin_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#title' => $this->t('Début de la période'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['horaire_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Horaire'),
    '#options' => $this->_horaires,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
    '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['cocktail_capacite_max_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => $this->t('Capacité max'),
    '#min' => 0,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['cocktail_capacite_min_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => $this->t('Capacité min'),
    '#min' => 0,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['repas_capacite_max_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => $this->t('Capacité max'),
    '#min' => 0,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">',
  ];

  $form['packages'][$i]['repas_capacite_min_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => $this->t('Capacité min'),
    '#min' => 0,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#suffix' => '</div></div></div>',
  ];
}

$form['ajouter_package'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Ajouter une période'),
  //'#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn btn-primary'], 'id' => 'add-package'],
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'AddPackageCallback'],
    'wrapper' => 'packages-wrapper',
  ],
  '#submit' => [$this, 'AddPackageSubmited'],
  '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
];

if ($nb_package > 1) {
  $form['retirer_package'] = [
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => $this->t('Retirer une période'),
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['btn btn-submit'],
      'event' => 'click',
      'id' => 'remove-package',
    ],
  ];
}

$form['ajouter'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Créer le bateau'),
];

    return $form;
  }
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

 public function AddPackageCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['packages'];
  }

  public function AddPackageSubmited(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $c = $form_state->get('nb_package') + 1;
    $form_state->set('nb_package', $c);
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }
}
```